# How can i convert a python script into a Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian) executable?

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, python-3

I'm designing a GUI for my Raspberry Pi 3 B+. I've written the code in Python3.5 and now I want my script to be run as executable (Raspbian package).

Is it possible to do so and if possible any solution is welcomed.

Comment: your question has nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi .... it is a Linux question

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ambiguous.

If what you want is to execute the python script at the command line add the shebang at the start of the script and mark it as executable.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
```

You can rename the script (omit the .py extension if desired).

If you want any user to be able to execute the script you need to put it in a directory on the path e.g. `/usr/local/bin` and ensure that all users have execute permission with `sudo chmod +x scriptname`

The script will remain a normal python program which can be examined by anyone with read permission.

If you want to convert to a compiled executable this can be done with some tools - this is a general Linux problem, not specific to the Pi.

Making a program executable from the GUI menu requires constructing a suitable LXDE desktop shortcut script.desktop. It is not easy to give generic instructions, but there are plenty of tutorials.

Comment: I've followed the same process but it still not working.

Comment: @VikashSharma "followed the same process" is unhelpful - actually list in your question **what YOU did** including the script

Answer (score 0):

Put the following line at the start of your script.

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

Make the script executable.

`chmod +x script.py`

Comment: The same is not executing for me

Comment: @VikashSharma You have done something wrong.

Comment: @VikashSharma What error message do you get if you try to run `/full/path/to/my/script.py` from the command line?

Comment: I get no error,  instead of the script doesn't work

Comment: Pass the popcorn...